# shows undefined varibale when data is send through template variable

Tags: php, variables, undefined

```
<?php   

    if(isset($_POST['c_number'])){

        $data = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM additiona_info WHERE citizenship_no = ' . $_GET['c_number'])->fetch();  
    }
     $templateVars = [
        'data' => $data
    ];      


$headingTitle = 'Mechinagar Municipality';
$content = loadTemplate('../view/marriage_referal_template.php', $templateVars);

?>
```

this is my code where i need to get data in variable through query and it should send its value through template variable to another page. but the data is called undefined in the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Found your problem you use `$_GET['c_number']` but on top you use `$_POST['c_number']`

So figure out which one you need the `$_GET` or `$_POST`

You can replace it with `$_REQUEST` to include both `$_GET` and `$_POST`

Like so

```
<?php   

    if(isset($_REQUEST['c_number'])){

        $data = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM additiona_info WHERE citizenship_no = ' . $_REQUEST['c_number'])->fetch();  
    }
     $templateVars = [
        'data' => $data
    ];      


$headingTitle = 'Mechinagar Municipality';
$content = loadTemplate('../view/marriage_referal_template.php', $templateVars);

?>
```